# Reading object's data from IBM Cloud Object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-storage

I'm learning about IBM COS and I haven't got a lot of details about one item in the docs. Could you please let me know if we can read the object data (row by row) after storing a .xlsx file in a bucket? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you save the .xlsx as .csv the upload to Cloud Object Storage you can query the data in place with IBM SQL Query.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/sql-query?topic=sql-query-overview